# How to configure TV and video recording and pausing?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-recording, tvtime

Set for television viewing tvtime, set up the remote, everything works fine.

But I would like to set up an opportunity to pause live TV and record video, is there a function in tvtime or may be I need to install another program?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for more DVR like capability, check out [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/).  It might be overkill, but it might give you something you didn't know you even wanted.

Comment: I agree this might be overkill for the situation you're talking about but it is a massively flexible piece of software and will certainly do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From http://tvtime.sourceforge.net/help.html#recording:

> tvtime does not support recording or playback of recorded streams

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to try [kaffeine](http://kaffeine.kde.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install kaffeine
```

Should be able to do what you are searching for.